# Simulating n games of craps in python

Tags: python-3.x, simulation

I'm pretty new to python and I have been trying to make this simulator that creates a simulator for "games" of craps. My professor wanted it to be made in the most basic form possible which is the reason for having a function for rolling one dice then another. For some reason I can't get my simOneGame function to cooperate and I can't even get it to print a value when I assign a variable to it although it should print a 1 or 0. Here is my code:

```
def main():
    x = eval(input("how many games will be played?: "))
    y = simNGames(x)
    print(y)

def simOneGame():
    win = 0
    lose = 0
    x = rollDice()
    if x == 2 or x == 3 or x == 12:
        lose += 1
    elif x == 7 or x == 11:
        win += 1
    y = rollDice()
    while y != 7 or y != x :
        y = rollDice()
    if y == x:
        win += 1
    elif y == 7 :
        lose += 1

    if win > lose:
        return(1)
    else:
        return(0)

def simNGames(n):
    wins = 0
    loses = 0
    x = simOneGame()
    for i in range(n):
        if x > 0:
            wins += 1
        else:
            pass
    frac = wins / n
    return float(frac)

def rollDice():
return rollDie() + rollDie()

def rollDie():
return randrange(1,7)
```

I don't get an answer unless input a number greater than 100 and it's always a 1.0

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues I see with your code.

First off, your `simNGames` only actually simulates one game, but then it adds up that game's results `n` times. You need to move your `x = simOneGame()` line inside the loop so that it gets called repeatedly.

There's a separate issue with your `simOneGame` function's logic. A single craps game is either won or lost, there's no scoring. That means you don't need to be adding up win and loss values. You should change all the places where you do `win += 1` to do `return 1` instead, and all the places that do `lose += 1` should be `return 0` (this means you can get rid of the rest of the code dealing with the `win` and `lose` variables too).

You also might consider returning `True` and `False` rather than 1 and 0, but this might have been decided by your teacher, and it's more a design style point than an error.

Finally, I think the while loop in `simOneGame` needs an `and` rather than an `or` to make the logic work correctly.

Comment: I think your suggestions might have made it work. Thanks a ton! I had realized the wins and loses thing in the simOneGame function before I saw what you wrote but why is it that I need an and instead of an or?

Comment: With the current logic it will loop forever if x is not 7. You want it to stop looping when either `y == 7` or `y == x`, but since the while condition is the inverse of that, you need to apply [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and flip the `and` for an `or` in addition to flipping the `==` for `!=`: `not (y == 7 or y == x)` <=> `y != 7 and y != x`